# Premiere CC 2015 and DVD conversion audio sync issue

Tags: premiere, audio, sync

Years ago, I transferred a video tape of a live band performance to DVD (using a Sony VHS/DVD RW machine that I no longer own). Yesterday, I edited an 8-minute clip from the DVD. The audio/video sync appeared fine inside Premiere, but when I exported to YouTube, the audio and video are completely out of sync.

(I didn't touch the alignment of either audio or video tracks while editing)

All I did was add titles to the beginning and end.

How can I prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: When you say *completely* out of sync -- by how much? Do they start out of sync and stay the same, or do they start in sync and drift out, or something else? Do the titles you added have an associated audio track (even if it's silent)?

Comment: titles have no audio track. Looking at my local copy of the rendered video, it appears that perhaps the audio track got moved to the beginning (i.e. filling in the blank space "under" the title). it's *seconds* ahead of the video. I'm a casual user of Premiere and I could have clicked a ripple edit tool by accident. Hmmm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment feedback, and as I suspected, it looks as if the main audio has 'slipped under' the new title video. An easy way to avoid this is to marry the titles with a silent audio track.

Comment: Thank you. Going forward I'll add that to my "best practices"

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your video has the same fps as the original video, usually it's 25/29fps. It could also be the format that you're exporting it to.